# Remove Unique key Constraint from model and Db using Liquibase

Tags: mysql, jhipster, liquibase

I Have a spring boot project and i had an entity with the unique key consraint on it. I don't want to remove this constraint manually as it could effect my CI/CD part but is there anyway i could do it using Liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

Sure if you are using YAML it may look like this:

```
changeSet:
  id: dropUniqueConstraint-example
  author: liquibase-docs
  changes:
  - dropUniqueConstraint:
      catalogName: cat
      constraintName: const_name
      schemaName: public
      tableName: person
      uniqueColumns: A String
```

Please find the documentation here: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/drop_unique_constraint.html

Comment: No, I am using the xml files and i had seen this documentation too, but now i dont't know that weather i should put it a separate change-log file and should mention it in my master.xml or should i need to mention it in my already present xml files.

Comment: You should create a new migration and add it to your master.xml. You should edit your entity class to remove the constraint in java too.

Comment: Every migration goes into a new file

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i created a new file and put this xml in it and mentioned that file in my master.xml too and i had changed my entity also.
But when i restart my application no changes in db are reflected.

Comment: do you see the SQL statements executed? Do you get any errors? Can you show the XML files

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  What you need to simply do is simply add this to your changelog file and let the CI/CD do its job. or is you have H2 configured locally you can see changes locally as well.

I copied below mentioned from official documentation, would be useful for you.

**XML**

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="dropUniqueConstraint-example">
    <dropUniqueConstraint catalogName="cat"
            constraintName="const_name"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="person"
            uniqueColumns="A String"/>
</changeSet>
```

**YML**

```
changeSet:
  id: dropUniqueConstraint-example
  author: liquibase-docs
  changes:
  - dropUniqueConstraint:
      catalogName: cat
      constraintName: const_name
      schemaName: public
      tableName: person
      uniqueColumns: A String
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "changeSet": {
    "id": "dropUniqueConstraint-example",
    "author": "liquibase-docs",
    "changes": [
      {
        "dropUniqueConstraint": {
          "catalogName": "cat",
          "constraintName": "const_name",
          "schemaName": "public",
          "tableName": "person",
          "uniqueColumns": "A String"
        }
      }]

  }
}
```